# Multi-choice memory stick?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, live-usb

Now, with large memory sticks being cheap, I think it would be nice to have many or all official flavours available on one memory stick. That is; you boot from a memory stick and get a menu which lets you choose between the most current version, the latest LTS, 32- and -64 bit, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc. This would make for a very nice way to demonstrate different flavours and also choose 32- or 64-bit as appropriate.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @WarrenHill: Why should it not be answerable? There is a duplicate, and I'll vote to close this question myself, but your comment made me curious.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad: I may have misread the question.  I took this more as a suggestion than as a "how can I do this".  But on re-reading it is a valid question, but a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I think **probably the best** (Linux) way to create a **Multi-OS Live USB Memory Stick** (if I understood you correctly), including **different Ubuntu flavors** as well as other live Operating Systems (e.g. **Parted Magic**, including **Clonezilla**, for backup, recovery and other maintenance purposes) is:

[**MultiSystem**](http://liveusb.info/)

which I've been using happily for several years now.

If you're not comfortable with French or Google-Translate-powered translation, you can also see furher info here: [www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)

Comment: Interesting, but Google translates it into "Multisystem disease", which will make it difficult to promote in Norway, at least. In any event, I'd like to know how to _do_ it and not just an application that can automate it.

Comment: English translation is quite satisfactory. Good luck with the manual work ;-) But it would be interesting if you can also find a way of keeping different persistent files (casper-rw) for different flavors of Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Yumi.  The only thing it runs under Windows or [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)

> YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer), is the successor to
>   MultibootISOs. It can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive
>   containing multiple operating systems, antivirus utilities, disc
>   cloning, diagnostic tools, and more.<sup>1</sup>

Just run it, choose an OS, click create, and once done, it will ask you if you want to add another.  Choose it click create, and so on.

[image]

For a utility that run under Linux, see [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Pen Drive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)</sup>