# Problem putting Ubuntu onto USB

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to download Ubuntu 12.04.2 onto my USB. So far I have a ISO to USB file downloaded onto my hard drive. When I try to copy it to my USB, I'm asked for an .iso file, but I cannot find it. What's wrong?

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/291050/multi-choice-memory-stick/291091#291091)

Comment: Where have you saved the downloaded ISO file? Maybe `/home/your_username/Downloads`?

Answer (score 0):

Copying the iso directly to your usb drive will not work. You need to use a special program to make the usb drive bootable and then copy the files over. Take a look at [this site](http://www.pendrivelinux.com). You'll find both programs and tutorials.

Comment: So when I tried that and it said "Step 2: Select your Ubuntu-12.04*desktop-amd.iso" in the box appears: "Browse to your ubuntu-12.04*desktop-amd.iso -->" and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You mean you cannot locate the .iso file you have downloaded? Check your browser configuration to see where it stores downloads by default.

Answer (score 0):

When you download Ubuntu, it should come as an .iso file. When it is finished downloading (during download, it will be a ".crdownload" file for Google Chrome and ".part" or something similar for Firefox), you must use an application to burn it to your USB drive. Ubuntu comes with one such application called "Startup Disk Creator." If you are using Windows, you can download Lili from http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ , I find it nice to use. In either of these applications, you select the .iso of Ubuntu you downloaded, your USB drive, and let it do the rest!

I hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone. I'm finding this process to b more difficult than it sounds. :/

Answer (score 0):

Follow these [steps](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) from the official Ubuntu site.